# How to read from a file using C# code?

Tags: c#, file-io, text-files, filestream

I have a file contains two lines . and in which line there is a `double` parameter .
I want to read both lines from the file and save them in an array of doubles .
I used the C# code below , but It doesn't work . It doesn't read anything and the array is empty after running the code . 
Anybody has any idea where did I do wrong ?
Thanks for help .

```
    private FileStream input;
    double[] arr;
    int i = 1;

    input = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath+"\\City.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(input); 

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            arr[i] = Convert.ToDouble(reader.ReadLine());
            i++;
        }

    reader.Close();
```

Comment: Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. We don't know whether you've even initialized `arr` anywhere.

Comment: did you run the debugger?  is the file opened?  does the loop process both lines?  is your text in a format that can be converted to a double?

Comment: I want to show the array parameters in two `textbox` .

Comment: the file contains two double parameters like below :>35.5>37.5

Comment: I created the file and saved 2 double parameters in it in another class . and now I want to use that parameters here . I Don't know where did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete example of what you are doing.

```
string line;
List<double> values = new List<double>();
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "City.txt");

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    values.Add(double.Parse(line));
}

file.Close();
```

Based on "[How to: Read a Text File One Line At a Time (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94223t4d.aspx)"

Answer (score 1):

try this approach

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(Application.StartupPath+"\\City.txt")) 
{
    string line;
    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
    // the file is reached. 
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
         arr[i] = Convert.ToDouble(line);
         i++;
    }
}
```

and you should at least initialize `arr`: `arr = new double[_size]` and `i` should be zero because arrays in c# are zero based. And better use generic collection like `List<T>`(`List<double>` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `while (!reader.EndOfStream)` because when you initially read it in the position is at the end of the file. This is solidified by the fact that the line `arr[i]` should fail because you've not initialized the array **(in fact, it shouldn't even compile...)**. So, how about this:

```
double[] arr = new double[2];
...

reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    arr[i] = Convert.ToDouble(reader.ReadLine());
    i++;
}
```

However, a more straight forward approach would be something like this:

```
var arr = new List<double>();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath+"\\City.txt");
foreach (var l in lines)
{
    arr.Add(Convert.ToDouble(l));
}
return arr.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa.aspx), considering that file size is small.

```
    string[] stringDoubles = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8);
    for(int i=0;i<stringDoubles.Length;i++)        
        arr[i] = Convert.ToDouble(stringDoubles[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code as you posted will not compile, because you have not initialized your array, as well as having a visibility modifier on your FileStream. I'd guess this code is from two different locations in your project.

However, there's a much simpler way to do this: `File.ReadAllLines`

```
string path = @"c:\dev\text.txt"; //your path here
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
double[] doubles = new double[2];
for (int i = 0; i < doubles.Length; i++)
{
    double d;
    if (double.TryParse(lines[i], out d))
        doubles[i] = d;
}
```